# How to create a new executable C# project with Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-code, exe, omnisharp

I want to create a new executable project with Visual Studio Code + omnisharp.
It works for dll but not for an exe file.

1. Created a folder for my new project (e.g. myApp)
2. Open Visual studio code -> file -> open folder
3. Open internal VSC terminal and type the following commands

Code:

```
dotnet new console (pressed yes in popup)
dotnet restore
dotnet run
//hello world was visible in terminal (what means it works)
dotnet build
```

Build was successful but a dll file was created.

- Actual result: dll file
- Expected result: exe file

BTW: I used this for help -> https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using dotnet core, so executable files are still in .dll. To run the file, run `dotnet nameofdll.dll`

`dotnet core` is cross-platform, and to reduce the tight coupling with windows, `.exe` is not used for executables anymore.

If you want your application to be Windows dependant, you will need to make your application target .Net Framework instead - you will get a .exe instead this way.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! changed target framework to <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework> and now seems to work

Answer (score -1):

If you go into the folder where the app is and go to bin/debug/net6.0,
I found a exe file along with four other files I have no idea what they do,
and a file called publish,
also try F1 and search for publish,
that might make these files appear
(publish seems to be the same 5 files outside of the publish file).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).